# Can't see soundbar volume level on my TV

Tags: android-tv, google-tv

I have a Sony HT-S20R sound system. It's connected to my TV using HDMI ARC. My TV is the latest (QLED with support for HDMI ARC and Google TV as OS).

But when I increase the volume using the TV remote, it changes the volume but doesn't show the current volume level which is very annoying.

Any solution for it? Both support S/PDIF Optical. Is it better and can solve the problem?